# Redirect naked to www with traefik

Tags: redirect, reverse-proxy, traefik, traefik-middleware, traefik-routers

I want to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`.

In the traefik container's `docker-compose.yml`, I defined a redirection middleware that I can use from multiple services:

```yaml
traefik:
  image: traefik
  # ...
  labels:
    traefik.http.middlewares.nakedtowww.redirectregex.regex: ^https?://(?:www\\.)?(.+)
    traefik.http.middlewares.nakedtowww.redirectregex.replacement: https://www.$${1}
    traefik.http.middlewares.nakedtowww.redirectregex.permanent: true
```

And a service:

```yaml
whoami:
  image: traefik/whoami
  # ...
  labels:
    traefik.enable: true
    traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule: Host(`${DOMAIN}`, `www.${DOMAIN}`)
    traefik.http.routers.whoami.middlewares: nakedtowww
```

When I visit either `https://example.com` or `https://www.example.com` it redirects to `https://www.www.example.com` and responds with 404.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One must define two routers:

```yaml
whoami:
  image: traefik/whoami
  # ...
  labels:
    # naked -> www
    traefik.http.routers.whoami-naked.entrypoints: websecure
    traefik.http.routers.whoami-naked.rule: Host(`${DOMAIN}`)
    traefik.http.routers.whoami-naked.middlewares: nakedtowww
    # www
    traefik.http.routers.whoami-www.entrypoints: websecure
    traefik.http.routers.whoami-www.rule: Host(`www.${DOMAIN}`)
```